How do I access the globalThis.ts object in monaco?
In the GitHub sources, I can see that globalThis.ts points to typescript as used by monaco. My first thought was that it would be available on window, but monaco uses a webworker, so has a different context to my code.
How can I programatically get access to that object?
Here's a link to a monaco sandbox, for tinkering
I appreciate any help on this one!
Edit: I can see that ts is available in the webworker in the Chrome console by selecting that window.

